# Hyphen Versus Parentheses

Tags: punctuation

So, I absolutely use too many parentheses in my writing and yet, I have what I consider parenthetic things that I want to express.  So what exactly should I do?  I've been playing around with hyphens for quite a while now, but I'm still not certain which is better (if either), when and why.  I hope this hasn't already been answered - I don't think it has, but...  Here is an example of that with which I wrestle as regards this matter:

1)  Please do feel free (and safe, as far as I'm concerned) to text me anytime you'd like.

2)  Please do feel free - and safe, as far as I'm concerned - to text me anytime you'd like.

OR

1)  Please remember that I voluntarily admitted to you that I had been indirect (and thus, less than honest) in asking you the question in the first place.

2)  Please remember that I voluntarily admitted to you that I had been indirect - and thus, less than honest - in asking you the question in the first place.

Thanks, guys! :-)

Comment: "Hyphen vs Parentheses" sounds like some epic battle from the Titanomachy, like "Typhon vs Prometheus"! :)

Comment: @tchrist I was going to suggest that hyphens should be replaced, for the purpose in this question, by dashes, but that would ruin your epic battle.

Comment: You’re talking about style, not rules. So read a good stylist, like Joan Didion (The White Album) to see how she handles this sort of thing.

Comment: You can also use commas parenthetically.

Comment: Thanks to you all!  I really like the "epic battle" reference, @tchrist!  And, @Andreas Blass, I was at first confused by your mention of the swap you mentioned until I realized that you meant that I was using the wrong word to describe my example here.  I am actually employing dashes rather than hyphens in this instance.  I honestly never knew that "hyphen" and "dash" weren't perfectly interchangeable.  Thank you much! :-)

Comment: This might be a better question for [writers.se]

Comment: I suspect the vast majority don't know the difference between hyphen and dash, and in most contexts it doesn't make a difference and you'll be understood perfectly well if you use the wrong one.

Comment: Not to mention em-dash versus en-dash.

Answer (score 1):

They have different uses. Parentheses add explanatory information to a sentence (this removes the need to make a whole new sentence) that is related to the subject matter. Em dashes show a change in thought — changing the subject mid-sentence was something Kant loved to do — that will eventually return to the original though.

In your examples, I would use commas.

> Please, as far as I am concerned, do feel free and safe to text me anytime you'd like.

> Please remember that I voluntarily admitted to you that I had been indirect, and thus less than honest, in asking you the question in the first place.

Do note that I changed the word order in the first example.

Comment: +1. This advice is ultimately opinion based, but it isn't something that Nate Murray just made up on the spot. I have seen and heard variations of the same argument from numerous editors and writers over the course of many years—and since this answer rather neatly expresses the view of what amounts to a particular school of conventional punctuation-style wisdom, I think it deserves respectful consideration—although not, certainly, unthinking obedience.